# How can I unset perticular enviroment variable's value??

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have 
PATH environment variables's value as:

```
/home/vinayak/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/vinayak/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I wish to delete only these values:

```
/home/vinayak/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/vinayak/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
```

How can unset only these two values? Please help.

Thanks in Advance.